# Customer shipping and billing display only one state and hide other states

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, billing, state, regions

I am developing an application where the customer is in Canada and the state [Quebec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec) only (no other states of Canada).

I wanted to make the customer choose only Quebec state and always Quebec only.
I googled lot for this to hide other states in the select box or to get only Quebec state. I am not getting where to change the code.

I checked if there's JavaScript code to take the role to display and hide the tabs in checkout. Where do I need to hide the other states or select only the Quebec state Id from database?

How can I restrict the customer to select only one Quebec state, only. Already Canada is the only country in the country selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer, Thanks Pradeepsanku,

```
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').val('CA'); // CA stands for the Canada
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').prop('disabled','disabled');

jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').val(76); // 76 stands for the Quebec
jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').prop('disabled','disabled');
```

I changed the code form

```
jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').prop('disabled','disabled');
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').prop('disabled','disabled');
```

To

```
jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').attr("readonly",true);
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').attr("readonly",true);
```

I come to know that what is the diff between .attr() and .prop().
from here

[Difference between .attr() and .prop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362153/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-make-an-input-readonly)

Thank you,

Comment: nice great ......

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code

```
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').val('CA'); // CA stands for the Canada
jQuery('#billing\\:country_id').prop('disabled','disabled');

jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').val(76); // 76 stands for the Quebec
jQuery('#billing\\:region_id').prop('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: On which page I need to add this?

Comment: in billing form page and shipping.phtml

Comment: Its working as I need, but when I click on continue it show "Please Enter Country" in alert Box. so I removed the disable code, Then again alert message for state as "Please Enter State".